# How to determine if I am using a Restful service or not?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest

I need to create a Restful service for my application. More I dig deep in to this more I get confused. I understand that a Restful service uses http for **CRUD** operations which makes it faster and lighter. But I am not sure how to determine if a web service is Restful or not.

However I found some help online that claims to be a Restful service but that has some **Custombinding** type . Here is how the web.config looks like

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="" name="RestRaw.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="RestRaw.IService1" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="RawReceiveCapable"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="RawReceiveCapable">
          <webMessageEncoding webContentTypeMapperType="RestRaw.RawContentTypeMapper, RestRaw, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="524288000"
           transferMode="Streamed" />
        </binding>

      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Is that a **Restful service**. If yes how can that be determined??

I am confused at the moment any suggestions to clarify my doubt would be really appreciated.

Comment: rest is a philosophy and a pattern with the *resources themselves*. readup on what consistutes REST: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: @JayeshGoyani not aways true.

Comment: you haven't shown your research into what REST is or your code other than config.

Comment: @Daniel A. White: that is what my doubt is all about...do we determine if a web service is Restful or not from the web.config tags??? If i have to figure out whether a particular web service is Restful or not what should I look for??

Comment: and does that web.config signify any thing about the architecture of web service?? or Is it like .a wcf service is always a Rest service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case you can tell it's a REST style webservice by the  added behavior.

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

The webHttp behavior modifies the operation dispatch pipeline and instead of reading a destination action from a SOAP body, it uses the service interface attributes to decide where to route it. [Here is a good page on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412172%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that shows the basics of creating a REST style webservice in WCF. The following example is from that page.

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ICustomer
{
  //"View It" -> HTTP GET
    [WebGet( UriTemplate="customers/{id}" )]
  Customer GetCustomer( string id ):

  //"Do It“ -> HTTP PUT
  [WebInvoke( UriTemplate="customers/{id}", Method="PUT" )]
  Customer UpdateCustomer( string id, Customer newCustomer );
}
```

The WebGet attribute matches the GET verb, then the request URI is pattern matched to decide which method to call. Then parts of the URI can be extracted and converted to parameters and passed to the method call. In the second method, UpdateCustomer, the Customer parameter comes from the request body as it's the only parameter that doesn't get matched elsewhere. In order for the request body to be used like this, the webMessageEncoding binding element is used in the custom binding. If you simply use the WebHttpBinding, it does all of this for you. The config you provided is doing it the explicit way.

Answer (score 1):

The web.config file shows a typical WCF application. To check whether it is RESTful, you might learn WCF REST related topics, such as

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx